# XML parsing works with Chrome and Firefox but fails on Internet Explorer

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, exception, dom, gwt

In my GWT project I am parsing a xml file:

```
Document document = XMLParser.parse(xmlString);
```

On Chrome and Firefox everything is fine. XML gets parsed succesfully and data retrieved is valid. But Internet Explorer 9 the line above fails with the following exception:

```
com.google.gwt.xml.client.impl.DOMParseException: Failed to parse: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?> 
<parsedVolcanoes> 
<volcano> 
<title>Vulkan Arenal in Costa Rica</t
```

Any hints what might be the problem are highly appreciated! I am aware the given information is sparse so please ask if you need more information.

I was able to solve the problem. There is a 0xffff character in xmlString. Removing fixes the problem. Here is the code:

```
// remove invalid characters from xml
xmlString = xmlString.replaceAll("\\uffff", "");

// parse the XML document into a DOM
Document document = XMLParser.parse(xmlString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `encoding="ISO-8859-1"` from your XML declaration.

> The second error indicates that you started off with a Unicode byte-order mark (or you called the LoadXML method), and then an encoding attribute specified something other than a 2-byte encoding (such as UTF-8 or Windows-1250)

— http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468560.aspx#xmlencod_topic3